# Can't `chmod` mount folder of read-only filesystem

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount, chmod

I have a directory (`mnt`) that has world read access, but when I mount a filesystem into it as readonly (as `root`) it subsequently shows no world permissions, and if I try to chmod it I get a readonly filesystem error.

**EDIT**

The question is perhaps a bit misguided - the goal was to make an NTFS mount available for world access when using the native Linux driver. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @stolenmoment points out, the new mountpoint permissions reflect the permissions of the mounted filesystem's root directory.

What you are *really* trying to do is allow `world` access to the filesystem for *this* mount, not edit filesystem's actual permission metadata. This can be necessary when mounting a `FAT` or `NTFS` filesystem where `FAT/NTFS` permission semantics do not match `UNIX` semantics - this causes the mounted filesystem to be accessable to the `mount`ing user only (when using the native Linux driver; `ntfs-3g` allows world access by default).

The solution is to `mount` the filesystem using `-o umask 000` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. The mount point takes on the identity of the root of the mounted file system.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: The post wasn't a question, either. However snippy, I did tell the poster why the permissions couldn't be changed. I'll endeavor to be less snarky...

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are trying to mount ntfs partition and for some reason it is mounting as read-only mode.

If this is the case try installing ntfs-3g and do remount again. It will work.

`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

Comment: I specifically want to mount it as read only. But I want to enable world read access.